# youtube search not getting URLS

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js

I'm trying to create a command that searches youtube for a video URL. When I run the command on its own, it sends the embed telling you to narrow your search. However, when I run the command + a query, it logs most of the video info in the console, but doesn't state the URL to the video itself, as well as not sending anything to the server. It doesn't log errors, and the bot stays online. How to fix this issue?

```js
const opts = {
  maxResults: 25,
  key: '(youtube api key)',
  type: 'video'
};

const search = require('youtube-search')

bot.on('message', async message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;

  if(message.content.toLowerCase() === 'a!play') {
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor("#73ffdc")
          .setDescription("Please enter a search query. Remember to narrow down your search.")
          .setTitle("YouTube Search API");
      let embedMsg = await message.channel.send(embed);
      let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
      let query = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1 });
      let results = await search(query.first().content, opts).catch(err => console.log(err));
      if(results) {
          let youtubeResults = results.results;
          let i  =0;
          let titles = youtubeResults.map(result => {
              i++;
              return i + ") " + result.title;
          });
          console.log(titles);
          message.channel.send({
              embed: {
                  title: 'Select which song you want by typing the number',
                  description: titles.join("\n")
              }
          }).catch(err => console.log(err));

          filter = m => (m.author.id === message.author.id) && m.content >= 1 && m.content <= youtubeResults.length;
          let collected = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { maxMatches: 1 });
          let selected = youtubeResults[collected.first().content - 1];

          embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle(`${selected.title}`)
              .setURL(`${selected.link}`)
              .setDescription(`${selected.description}`)
              .setThumbnail(`${selected.thumbnails.default.url}`);

          message.channel.send(embed);
      }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say most informations are logged. Maybe everything was right and it's just that since you gave the api the url it doesn't need to give it back as an information. Try maybe with an eval command or creating your own command logging informations for a random video like

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNCdYSzRKpU

And see if it doesn't give you the link. If it doesn't then it's perfectly normal and the api just doesn't return it, if it does than you should add the api tag or search for the youtube-search documentation